# istio-ingress can't start up

Tags: kubectl, minikube, istio

When I start minikube and apply istio.yaml
bug the ingress can't start up:

```
    eumji@eumji:~$ kubectl get pods -n istio-system 
NAME                             READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
istio-ca-76dddbd695-bdwm9        1/1       Running            5          2d
istio-ingress-85fb769c4d-qtbcx   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   67         2d
istio-mixer-587fd4bbdb-ldvhb     3/3       Running            15         2d
istio-pilot-7db8db896c-9znqj     2/2       Running            10         2d
```

When I try to see the log I get following output:

```
eumji@eumji:~$ kubectl logs -f istio-ingress-85fb769c4d-qtbcx -n istio-system 
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I1214 05:04:26.193386       1 main.go:68] Version root@24c944bda24b-0.3.0-24ec6a3ac3a1d592d1873d2d8198278a849b8301
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I1214 05:04:26.193463       1 main.go:109] Proxy role: proxy.Node{Type:"ingress", IPAddress:"", ID:"istio-ingress-85fb769c4d-qtbcx.istio-system", Domain:"istio-system.svc.cluster.local"}
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I1214 05:04:26.193480       1 resolve.go:35] Attempting to lookup address: istio-mixer
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I1214 05:04:41.195879       1 resolve.go:42] Finished lookup of address: istio-mixer
Error: lookup failed for udp address: i/o timeout
Usage:
  agent proxy [flags]


      --serviceregistry string            Select the platform for service registry, options are {Kubernetes, Consul, Eureka} (default "Kubernetes")
      --statsdUdpAddress string           IP Address and Port of a statsd UDP listener (e.g. 10.75.241.127:9125)
      --zipkinAddress string              Address of the Zipkin service (e.g. zipkin:9411)

Global Flags:
      --log_backtrace_at traceLocation   when logging hits line file:N, emit a stack trace (default :0)
  -v, --v Level                          log level for V logs (default 0)
      --vmodule moduleSpec               comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging

ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E1214 05:04:41.198640       1 main.go:267] lookup failed for udp address: i/o timeout
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in your post to figure out what may be wrong, in particular it seems that somehow your ingress isn't able to resolve istio-mixer which is unexpected.

Can you file a detailed issue
https://github.com/istio/issues/issues/new

And we can take it from there ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something like minikube? The quick-start docs give this hint: "Note: If your cluster is running in an environment that does not support an external load balancer (e.g., minikube), the EXTERNAL-IP of istio-ingress says . You must access the application using the service NodePort, or use port-forwarding instead."

https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start.html

Comment: you did say you're using minikube. :D so, maybe that helps.